# Banco de dados no Android persiste as informações?

Tags: android, banco-de-dados

O banco de dados perde suas informações ao fechar a aplicação? No caso deve ser um banco de dados online?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Um banco de dados existe justamente para persistir dados. Quando coloca nele, fica lá até a aplicação apagar, ou o próprio usuário interferir de alguma forma fora do seu controle.

Obviamente tudo o que for colocado em um banco de dados no dispositivo só pode ser acessado ali. O mais usado no cenário apresentado é o SQLite.

Se por qualquer motivo tiver que centralizar os dados em algum lugar ou tê-los no servidor para poder realizar o que deseja, então os dados precisam ser enviados pela internet e provavelmente guardados em um banco de dados no servidor.

A dúvida é simples, mas pertinente. Só sugiro aprender sobre todo processo de desenvolvimento de software antes de começar fazer algo. Um passo de cada vez.